# Given any non-zero $a,b$ and $n$, to show that there exist integer $k$ and $l$, such that $gcd(k,l)=1$ and $n\mid ak+bl$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given any non-zero $a,b$ and $n$, how to show that there exist integer $k$ and $l$, such that $gcd(k,l)=1$ and $n\mid ak+bl$.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that $a,b,n$ are arbitrary, $k$ and $l$ should be chosen such that $a\vert k$ and $a\vert l$; then $a$ divides any linear combination of $k,l$.

Comment: @Akay In that case $gcd(k,l) \neq 1.$

Comment: Oh..yes. What if we try cases:
If at least one of $a,b$ is divisible by $n$, then at least one of $k,l$ is 1, (suppose $n|a$, so $k=1$)and then $l$ can be chosen s.t. $n|bl$. All that is left is to show existence in case $n$ divides neither of $a, b$.

Comment: @Akay The most important case is the last one that you mentioned.

Comment: @bor: Are you sure the claim is true?

Comment: "All that is left to show is..."  That has to be one of the most blithe understatement I've read today.

Answer (score 3):

Let $d=gcd(a, b)$.

Let $k=b/d$ and $\ell = (bn-1)a/d$. Obviously $n \mid ka + \ell b$ and $gcd(k, \ell) = 1$.